# Would it be appropriate to ask to bring along my partner to an overseas office visit?

Tags: united-states, europe, travel, international

I live and work in the EU, for the local branch of a global company. The company's headquarters are in the US.

I have plans to go there for vacation soon, and I'll be staying a few days in the city where my company has its headquarters.
So I sent out an email to my colleagues who work in that office to ask if I could visit them, and got a positive reply saying that they'd be happy to show me around.

The thing is, I'll be traveling with my significant other (who does not work for the same company, just to be clear). Would it be ok for me to ask if I could bring them along to the visit, or I'd better ask my partner to find themselves something else to do for that part of the day (I expect this visit to take no longer than couple of hours in the morning)?

I doubt we'd talk about anything too work-related (honestly, I'll be on vacation and the less I'll talk about work the better :D ), so I don't have any concerns about "trade secrets" or anything like that: my "goal" for the visit would just be to meet in person and shake hands with the people I've been emailing with for a couple of years (and that's the goal of the US colleagues as well, I assume).

I'm just wondering if asking if I could bring them along is "appropriate" or not, as I'm not too familiar with US work culture (I've lived and worked in the EU my whole life).

Comment: Ask your HR department... but I'd just play it safe and skip the idea entirely.

Comment: Probably wouldn't take your partner to the office - but there's nothing to stop you planning a social meal with some colleagues and inviting their significant others for balance, if you're in town.

Comment: Why would your partner need to come with you if this is not your home office with the people you work with daily?

Comment: It's not clear to me if you mean to visit these colleagues at the office or if you're just planning to meet up in the city/outside of business hours. Depending on that my answer would differ.

Comment: Would you bring your partner to a work event in your home town or to your hometown workplace? If you wouldn't then don't bring them to any other office. If you would bring them, or your partner often comes into your office, then ask yourself if it's because they are friends with the other people in your local office, and how well do they know the overseas people and would they have the same relationship.

Answer (score 12):

Depends. If the activity is mostly work related, it' better to show up alone. If it's mostly social, then it's perfectly fine to bring your partner along.

If the activity happens on company premises and/or during active work time, than it's probably more work than social. If you have a bunch of meet & greet meeting in the office, don't bring your partner: it would be boring anyway. If you do a sightseeing tour of the city with dinner, by all means bring them.

There is alway a bit of a grey area that depends somewhat on the specific corporate culture. In many places a tour of the facilities (especially if they are cool) followed by lunch in the cafeteria would also be perfectly fine for your partner. In others this may violate a policy or raise security concerns.

If in doubt, just ask.

Comment: I think there are some businesses where it's normal to bring in spouses, kids, etc, to the workplace. But that varies a lot by industry and company. Maybe if it's a public facing business like a shop or beautician it would be more normal to have different people around, but if you wouldn't bring your spouse to your local office, then you shouldn't be bringing them to any other office.

Answer (score 2):

It would typically be unusual for a partner to tag along for a workplace tour, but if the office has a cafeteria or other commons area they may be allowed to hang around there during the trip. But some companies might not like the idea of a non-employee being unattended for hours at a time.

If your concern is mostly the logistic of splitting up during the day you can ask if the office has a cafe or somewhere your partner can grab a coffee and read a book, or your colleagues might be able to at least recommend someplace like that nearby the office.